# New close reason suggestion for health and legal question

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Recently we got [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/28495/chronic-hand-pain-and-stiffness-and-guitar-playing) and over my time here I feel that there have been other questions where the only advice we can give is to see a doctor, lawyer, ect.

Off the top of my head here are two that stand out to me:

- https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/15955/co-writing-with-others
- [Blackout during practicing oboe](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/23666/blackout-during-practicing-oboe)

We already state that [legal issues are off topic in our FAQ](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and while we may be able to answer some questions that revolve around pain when practicing/preforming we obviously can't fully diagnose any reasons for pain or address medical issues. Below is a suggested close reason that would cover both health and legal questions.

> While this question is about music, it requires the attention of a professional that cannot be provided here. Please go see the related professional.

Any thoughts/suggestions/feedback?

Answer (score 7):

It does take a reasonably big need to change out one of our existing close reasons for another (the functionality isn't there to just add a new one in addition to the existing ones). While I agree that like on Parenting SE, some questions do just come down to "See a doctor - don't ask random internet folks", I don't know that it requires a whole new close reason, and here's why:

- There is always the 'other' reason vote to close option
- It may be good to have questions like this one so someone with the same issue in future sees a big "Go to the doctor" answer

Comment: So we can't add new close reasons at all?

Comment: We have 3 off-topic close reasons: not about music, belongs on other site, or 'other' - so we'd have to lose one of them to have this. Another option is editing it into the 'not about music' reason. Or possibly just using the not about music reason as it is.

Comment: @DrMayhem Did you mean there can only be a maximum of 3 reasons to close ?

Comment: @user2808054 Only 3 listed default options.  However we can still have more than 3 off-topic topics!  There just won't be a nice pre-formatted comment for it

Answer (score 0):

Exclusion of legal and health questions should be done in the [help center](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). For legal question, it is already done, whence there is no need for a new off-topic reason, the default one links there anyways.

For medical questions, a boundary has to be set up, since we [obivously allow some medical questions](https://music.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=pain%20is%3aq) and the answer is not always "go visit the doctor".

Answer (score 0):

I really think this would be a good idea. There do seem to be quite a few questions where "don't listen to us, see a doctor" it the only sensible answer.